# Update $scope with $resource

Tags: angularjs

Why is only the one that don't use $resource.get() work? I am using kendo-angular to update. Has this something to do with async? The main variable looks exactly the same so this has to have something to do with $resourse. What am I missing`

This works:

```
app.controller('SubjectCntrl', ['$scope', 'categoryService', function($scope, categoryService) {

    var main = categoryService.getCategories();
    var subjects = {
        data : [main]
    };
    $scope.subjects = {
        dataSource: subjects
    };
}]);
```

This does not:

```
app.controller('SubjectCntrl', ['$scope', 'categoryService', 'ApiFactory', function($scope, categoryService, ApiFactory) {
    ApiFactory.get(function(categoriesData) {
       var main = categoryService.getCategories();

       var subjects = {
           data : [main]
        };
        $scope.subjects = {
            dataSource: subjects
        };
    });
}]);
```

The factory:

```
app.factory('ApiFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/rest/forum/categories/1');
}]);
```

Service:

```
app.service('categoryService', ['$resource',  function($resource){


    this.getCategories = function(){
        var farmingSubjects = [ {text: "Poteter", spriteCssClass: "subject"}, {text: "Agurk", spriteCssClass: "subject"} ];
        var forestSubjects = [ {text: "Tall", spriteCssClass: "subject"}, {text: "Gran", spriteCssClass: "subject"} ];
        var animalSubjects = [ {text: "Hundar", spriteCssClass: "subject"}, {text: "Katter", spriteCssClass: "subject"} ];

        var farming = { text: "Jordbruk", items: farmingSubjects };
        var forest = { text: "Skogshold", items: forestSubjects };
        var animals = { text: "Dyrebruk", items: animalSubjects };

        var subjects = [farming, forest, animals ];

        var main = { text: "Huvudemner", expanded: true, items: subjects};
        return main;
    };
}]);
```

Edit: The success function is called without doubt.

```
   ApiFactory.get(function(data){
        console.log('success, got data: ', data);       
    }, function(err){
        alert('request failed');
    });
```

Comment: Show `categoryService` code.

Comment: If the call to `ApiFactory` fails then your callback code would not get called.

Comment: @Chandermani please see edit: It just returns data. Nothing strange.

Comment: I think it has something to do with angular-kendo. A regular variable works. Maybe something async?

Answer (score 0):

I think the second case is not working because you `ApiFactory` call is failing. The callback you have declared is for success.

Comment: It is being called. I can log it in both cases. Only error is that scope is not being updated.

Comment: I will try to add one for error. Will search for that. But logging data categoriesData past in as parameter looks fine.